# Cloudflare SSL certificate on IIS: "Windows does not have enough information to verify this certificate"

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

So I am trying to make my IIS8 webserver https, yet I can't seem to get it to work.
I have tried almost anything... but nothing seems to work.

**DON'T WORRY THE FILES BELOW ARE FAKE!**

---

[image: The private key!]
**PICTURE 1 KEY**

[image: The pem...]
**PICTURE 2 PEM**

---

First of all, what do I need to do with these 2? It says to save them as .key and .pem files, so I thought they mend: put the private key in a text file and save it as **.key** and same for the certificate and save it as **.pem**.

I tried to convert them to .pfx because that is what I need, right?

First I tried using openssl, but I saw a nice site, so I started using that instead: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html. That gave me an error at first, but then I saw cloudflare also had something called DER:

---

[image]

---

Which gave me an **.CRT** file if I downloaded it, so now I had a **.PEM**, a **.KEY** and an **.CRT** file, I went back to the website and used the **.CRT** file and the **.KEY** file, and put in a password!

Now I've gotten my **.PFX** file, which I wanted! I installed it on my windows server, but got this:

---

[image]

---

Why is it not verified?!

1. What files do I need to verify this?
2. Am I saving the files correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Within IIS you'll need to create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) and export it.

In the Crypto app, scroll down to the Origin Certificates card and click 'Create Certificate'. Select 'I have my own private key and CSR', add the hostnames you'd like to be covered by the certificate. Once you've completed all the steps in the Wizard you can go back to IIS and click " Complete Certificate Request".

[image: IIS Complete Signing Request]

A step-by-step breakdown of these instructions is available on the Cloudflare Knowledge Base: [Managing Cloudflare Origin CA certificates](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217557568-How-to-install-an-Origin-CA-certificate-in-Microsoft-IIS-8-and-8-5)

Additionally, you'll need to install the Origin CA root certificates for CloudFlare on the server outline in [Step 4](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/217557568-How-to-install-an-Origin-CA-certificate-in-Microsoft-IIS-8-and-8-5) of the KB tutorial. This is fix the warning message:

> Windows does not have enough information to verify this certificate.

There are two locations which these certificates may be installed: Current User or Local Machine.

1. To target the Current User open the `certmgr.msc` program, otherwise open `certlm.msc`
2. Expand 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities'
3. Right-click 'Certificates'
4. Select 'Import...' from the 'All Tasks' menu
5. Import both the ECC and RSA `.pem` files